# Help understanding this 'Fractal' I've just made?

Tags: fractals

I was messing around in C++, making an image where the pixels change depending on the the rectangle's dimensions and whether or not the space bar is down, and I formed this image:

[image]
Could anyone explain why such a drastic change exists between the bottom left corner area and the rest?

I've never seen a fractal where a region is so unlike the rest (since after all, most fractals are have similar structures throughout and always repeat upon sufficient magnifications).

Also, forgive me if this image does not count as a fractal. Calling it a fractal is the only thing I can think to call it, due to the repetitive nature of the top right corner area.

Code:

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <math.h>

Game::Game( HWND hWnd,const KeyboardServer& kServer )
:   gfx ( hWnd ),
kbd( kServer ),
r(100), 
g(100),
b(100),
boxX(1),
boxY(1),
boxW(600),
boxH(300)



 {}

void Game::Go()
{
        gfx.BeginFrame();
    ComposeFrame();
    gfx.EndFrame();
}

void Game::ComposeFrame()
{
    int y = boxY;
    while (y < boxY+boxW)
    {
        int x = boxX;
        while(x < boxX + boxW + 200)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(x, y, r/(45)*(x%y*(50-x)+25/x*y), g*(32)/(y%x*(y+23)+76*y/x), b/(32)*(x%y*(42-x)+75/x*y));
            x++;
        }
        y++;
    }
    if(kbd.SpaceIsPressed())
    {
        int x = boxX;
        int y = boxY;
        r = r/(45)*(x%y*(50-x)+25/x*y);
        g = g/(45)*(x%y*(50-x)+25/x*y);
        b = b/(45)*(x%y*(50-x)+25/x*y);

        if(r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 0)
        {
            r = 100;
            b = 100;
            g = 100;

        }
    }
    if(kbd.RightIsPressed())
    {

        boxX = boxX + 8;
    }
    if(kbd.LeftIsPressed())
    {
        boxX = boxX - 8;
    }
    if(kbd.UpIsPressed())
    {
        boxY = boxY - 8;
    }
    if(kbd.DownIsPressed())
    {
        boxY = boxY + 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the associated sourcecode.

Comment: I was weary about doing that since we're not on stack overflow but okay.

Comment: I don't think it's a fractal.

Comment: I think the lack of total self similarity fails it too. Also, sorry for the poor organization and overall messiness of the code. I was fooling around.

Comment: Some cellular automata have output that looks like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=cellular+automata

Comment: Like @QiaochuYuan says, this cellular automaton has a region of periodicity next to a chaotic region:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rule30.html